# How can I import all function from same named modules in different django app?

Tags: python, django

Django can auto import `views.py, models.py, urls.py` and so on in each app.
Now I write some signals, and I want to import receiver functions from each app.  The problem is how do I import all functions from a file named `receiver.py` in each app?

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: Django doesn't auto import anything.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Do you mean that I should add app name to settings first? But it is automatic after settings completed, I want to make my code act like what django does.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'd define signals in my app's `models.py`.  If you'd like to keep them in a separate file, I'd just import that file into `models.py`.

You might also look at splitting `models.py` into a package instead of a single module.

For example:

```
models.py
```

Becomes:

```
models/
|- __init__.py
|- base.py
`- receivers.py
```

Where your `__init__.py` just imports the child modules.

Something like:

```
# __init__.py
from .base import *
from .receivers import *
```